# How do I populate a library by mapping a network drive?

Tags: 2010, workflow, library, webdav

I am pretty new to SharePoint, and have been asked to populate a library with an automatically generated report. The report comes out once a day for three weeks at the beginning and end of every academic term. We are using SharePoint 2010.
It has been suggested that I look into WebDAV to accomplish this. I am not quite sure where to start, would I use WorkFlows or something similar to configure the automation? Or is there something between SP and the network drive that I need to configure? A script to write and then bounce into SP? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map a network drive to a SharePoint Library.

- [Here](http://mroffice365.com/2012/02/using-sharepoint-document-library-as-a-network-drive/) is a tutorial
- [Here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/blog/webguide/2010/07/01/mapping-network-drives-to-sharepoint-libraries/) is another one

Behind the scene, it uses WebDAV to communicate with SharePoint.
If you just want to push some files, this may be a good solution.

Afterwards, you just need to put your reports in the network drive.

And by the way, a workflow is not a good solution for this need.

Comment: Is a workflow not a good solution because it just adds unnecessary bulk? Or is are workflows simply not designed and tailored for this sort of thing?

Comment: A workflow is not designed for these sort of things. And it adds complexity for nothing.

You could also make a Windows Service that scan a folder every X minutes, and upload automatically on SharePoint new files on it.

Comment: Hello Sylvain, would I write a script that checks the folder every X minutes? Or is there actual windows functionality for a creating a Windows Service that does that?

Comment: With the Network drive solution you don't need to do anything.
Another solution, is indeed to make an application / service that will upload new files to SharePoint. I just checked and there is the FileSystemWatcher class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) that can listen the modification on file system and can trigger an event. The logic behind should be encapsulated inside a windows service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) if you want it to start automatically. But as I said, just the network drive is enough.

Comment: No, not really. Just need the right to add elements. The Contribute Permission should be OK.

Comment: Ok, and one more: Any performance issues I have to worry about? Is there a setting where I can set how often it checks the folder for a new document to upload so it doesn't bog down while checking the folder for new content? Thanks Sylvain, I appreciate the help

Comment: There is no timer or such a thing. A network drive is "the physical representation" of your document library.  It is not like Skydrive or Dropbox : there is no synchronisation. When you put a file on that network drive, it directly goes to the SharePoint Document Library

Answer (score 0):

If your environment supports incomming email, you could set up an email address for a document library and just email the file to the document library's address and the report will show up.